# ElasticSearch_ModelFieldNotMappedError

Tags: django, python-3.x, elasticsearch

I'm using `Django Elasticsearch` version `6.1.0` and currently I'm getting this kind of error:

```
django_elasticsearch_dsl.exceptions.ModelFieldNotMappedError:
  Cannot convert model field 'price' to an Elasticsearch field
```

Here is my **models.py**

```
class Product(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=2)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
```

and here's the **documents.py**

```
from django_elasticsearch_dsl import DocType, Index
from crudapp.models import Product

product = Index('products')

@product.doc_type
class ProductDocument(DocType):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['description', 'price', 'quantity']
```

Can anyone help me with this ?

Comment: Can you show your `Product` class? And does your index already exist in ES? If yes, can you show its mapping?

Comment: Here's the product class 
https://pastebin.com/rWYajndz

And my index doesn't exist in ES

Answer (score 1):

The decimal field it is causing this error.
delete it from fields, and do something like this.

```
  from django_elasticsearch_dsl import DocType, Index,fields


  class ProductDocument(DocType):
      price = FloatField(attr=None, **elasticsearch_properties)

      class Meta:
      . . .. . . . .
```